# Swift : Redundant conformance of Viewcontroller to protocol UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I want to add two frameworks `SWRevealViewController` and `SLKTextViewController` but I get this weird error.

I read about this error but it seems confusing.

> Redundant conformance of Viewcontroller to protocol UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

```
class Viewcontroller: SLKTextViewController,SWRevealViewControllerDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    // a lot of functions and code

}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you try to conform to the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` two times. One time explictily be writing it in the beginning and the second time by extending `SLKTextViewController` which already conforms to it - [the source code of `SLKTextViewController`](https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController/blob/master/Source/Classes/SLKTextViewController.h) consists of the following line:

```
NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) @interface SLKTextViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

which among other protocols already lists the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`!

**Solution**: remove the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` by changing your code to

```
class Viewcontroller : SLKTextViewController, SWRevealViewControllerDelegate {
```